# Show that $ \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/4}} $ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, differential-topology, polar-coordinates

I tried with polar coordinates, I found the limit is infinite (which is not true the graph show it's 0). I tried to majorate with something who has for limit 0 but still impossible.

with polar coordinates :
For $r > 0$ and $t \in [0,2\pi[ $, let $x=r\cos(t)$ and $y=r\sin(t)$, we have $$\frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/4}}=\frac{r^2\cos(t)^2}{(r^2\cos(t)^2+r^2\sin(t)^2)^{3/4}}=\frac{r^2\cos(t)^2}{(r^2)^{3/4}}=\frac{r^2}{r^{6/4}}\cos(t)^2=\sqrt{r}\cos(t)^2$$

Comment: *Hint:* $x^2 \le x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Polar coordinates should also work – what exactly did you calculate?

Comment: Please include your work in your use of polar coordinates, please, Loca.

Comment: I tried with this, here my work : $x^2\leqslant x^2+y^2 \Leftrightarrow x^{8/3}\leqslant(x^2+y^2)^{4/3}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x^{8/3}}\geq \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^{4/3}}\Rightarrow \frac{1}{x^{2/3}} \geqslant \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^{4/3}}$

Comment: That does not make use of polar coordinates, like you claim to have used, Loca.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, @Loca.  In the future, please edit your question post with added information, instead of using comments.

Comment: $\sqrt{r}\cos(t)^2 \le \sqrt{r}$, so you are almost done.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get the comment, 2 things is difficult to understand for me here, the fact that the limit can change depending on the value of $t$, (for example 0 or $\pi$ ), the fact that you majorate with something which tends to infinity.

Comment: Loca, note that $\cos^2 t \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: It's clear ! Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @MartinR, consider the inequality $x^{2} \leq x^{2} + y^{2}$ and apply the squeeze theorem:
\begin{align*}
0\leq \frac{x^{2}}{(x^{2} + y^{2})^{3/4}} \leq \frac{x^{2} + y^{2}}{(x^{2} + y^{2})^{3/4}} = (x^{2} + y^{2})^{1/4} \xrightarrow[]{(x,y)\to(0,0)} 0
\end{align*}

Hopefully this helps!